# A Node Setup that converts a greyscale bump texture into an RGB normal map... possible?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, normals, eevee-render-engine, pbr

I want to create a pbr texture (voronoi based) and then have it converted procedurally into a normal map, which can then be plugged in to the normal node.   (do not want to use bump node)  Surely this is possible with the correct math and the correct node setup...

Comment: Why don't you want to use the bump node?

Comment: because it causes pixellation at small scales... or so I've read in the blender documentation

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html). It will work just fine with procedural noise as input. If you'd use an image texture, then of course it's limited by the resolution of the image and may look pixelated on close-up.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html#materials

Comment: "As of now, bump mapping is supported using OpenGL derivatives which are the same for each block of 2x2 pixels. This means the bump output value will appear pixelated. It is recommended to use normal mapping instead."   Does this only apply to images?

Comment: I see, no this applies in general, if you're using Eevee and not Cycles. You can try the bump node and see if the effect is noticeable for your use case.